# Incoming Call Number is not showing Using Sinch Client to Call in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sinch

Thanks in advance.

I am developing one app in iOS.But have one Problem.

I am using `SINCH CLIENT` to make phone call from app to phone.But facing one problem when make call to other number on that device not showing actual number. and Showing incoming call from `+11111` like this number.

I have to show actual phone number who call.

Please help me.

Thanks Again

Comment: By contacting sinch and using the verification product you can do that. We do need to review your app to make sure its not a spoof app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jignesh Patel, you have to write to support of Sinch to explain about your app in brief. 
All the Sinch users will not have real number caller id feature enabled by default.

Sinch would verify all the aspects and then they may enable this feature for your account or for a specific app. And then you can see real numbers on the screen to whom you called (if the calling number is verified with Sinch verification service).

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In [Documentation of Sinch Client](https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/ios/), they have mentioned :

> Instead of invoking the `callUserWithId:` method, invoke the
> `callPhoneNumber:` method on the SINCallClient object.

So your App should know the phone number of the current device and you have to pass number in above method.